# If Field is Empty in Salesforce

Tags: if-statement, salesforce, report

I have a report in Salesforce where I would need to use an "if"-logic, but I don't know if it's possible.

I have two columns. Column A (object1) and column B (object2)
Column A is sometimes empty, but column B always has a value/text.

I want to apply an if-logic that says "If column A is empty, show text of column B/object 2 in that case".

Is it possible to do this?

At the end I should see a report where column A is never empty.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Read up about [`BLANKVALUE`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_blankvalue.htm&type=5) function. You can use it in a normal formula field (if there's clear relation between A and B) or in a report's [row-level formula](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_formulas_row_level_add.htm&type=5).

This is a terrible idea for any real application - but here's providing Account's City if Contact's City is blank.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. Technically it's config, not programming related. If you ask these on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ you might answers faster, more admins & consultants over there

Comment: Good point! Thanks a lot! :)